# Add row to pandas data frame causes prediction failure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

What is the best way to add a row to training data?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Features=x / Labels=y
new_train1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,3,4,4],
        'B': [4,5,6,6,4,3],
        'C': ['a','b','c','ddd','c','ddd']})
new_train2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1],
        'B': [4],
        'C': ['a']})
# Add new_train2's row to new_train1.
```

Maybe this would work:

```
new_train1 = new_train1.append(new_train2)
new_train1 = new_train1.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Finally, the data is split into features and labels.

```
new_train_x = new_train1.iloc[:,0:1] # Cols A and B
new_train_y = new_train1['C']
```

EDIT: Notably, after attempting this process (to add a row), here is the confusion matrix (#s are from real data set, not above sample set):

```
[[336   0   7   0   3   0]
 [ 23   8 358   0   0   3]
 [  0   0 373   1   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 281  30  25]
 [  0   0   0  14 220  33]
 [  0   0   0   6  14 265]]
```

Whereas prior to adding the row (and whenever dropping one row multiple times), here is the typical confusion matrix (once again using #s from real data not above sample data):

```
[[343   0   0   0   3   0]
 [  2 349  39   0   0   2]
 [  0  52 322   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 330   3   3]
 [  0   0   0   3 261   3]
 [  0   0   0   2   1 282]]
```

And here is the confusion matrix before adding or removing any data points:

```
[[343   0   0   0   3   0]
 [  3 355  31   0   0   3]
 [  0  30 344   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 331   1   4]
 [  0   0   0   1 261   5]
 [  0   0   0   3   4 278]]
```

Comment: If you want to extract a dataframe, use `new_train_y = new_train[['C']]`

Comment: Ah interesting.

Comment: Eventually, the idea is something like the following (which is causing some _issues_):
 
    new_train_x.loc[-1] = old_train_x.loc[4].copy()
    new_train_y.loc[-1] = old_train_y.loc[4]

Comment: Sorry, could I trouble you to post your expected output for the data given?

Comment: Well, kind of interesting. Here is a confusion matrix:
[via kaggle](https://www.kaggle.io/svf/1747461/c888ab39f168208bde10a25563c69412/__results___files/__results___14_2.png). It is from here (if you go here, it's really jumbly code right now - in progress) [kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/asdf99/testing/). Basically, there are 2000 training rows. And the accuracy score is 0.97. However, adding one row to these 2000 (one to features, one to labels) is throwing off the accuracy big time of a certain label ("SITTING"). TLDR: Add 1 row w/o borking linked confusion matrix.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, why do you want to add a row?

Comment: Not at all :) The idea is to add one row to training set and train a model. Say 2001 data points. Then make a prediction with a test set. Do this 1000 times, each time training with a different 2001th data point. After each prediction, save the accuracy score. When it is all done see what the benefit is of adding 1 row, based on increase in accuracy.

Comment: It's unclear how to answer your question. The confusion matrix is a complex function across the whole dataset, and you've only given us toy data here. It's entirely possible that your confusion matrix _should_ be "borked" with the addition of the new data. If you're trying to figure out if you've correctly added a new row to the dataframe, just check the dataframe itself to see if it's there, not some complex downstream calculation on it.